# Including DeviceCapability in appx file generated by pwabuilder

Tags: progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

I need to upload a progressive web app appx file generated by pwabuilder.com to the MicroSoft partner Center. It must include  in its list of capabilities

I could not see any way to add capabilities during the pwabuilder.com appx generation process. So I

- renamed windows.appx to windows.zip
- unzipped windows.zip
- edited AppxManifest.xml and added in the location capability *DeviceCapability Name="location"*
- zipped it up again
- renamed it back to windows.appx
- submitted it to the Microsoft partner center

Without adding the capability in the appx file upload fine but with the capability in I get

Package acceptance validation error: The package file format for windows.appx is invalid: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80510007. Update the package and try again.

How can I include the capability and get the package uploaded ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above error was a certificate signing error. The solution was to add the following to the web app manifest file

```
"mjs_capabilities": [
  "location"
],
```

and submit as before using pwabuilder.com . Full details at

https://github.com/pwa-builder/PWABuilder-CLI/wiki/Accessing-the-Windows-10-Runtime